# Telas Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import Saque

#Propriedades da Janela Principal
JanMenu = Tk() #JanMenu é uma instância da Classe Tk;
JanMenu['bg'] = 'white' #Cor de Fundo da Janela = Branco
JanMenu.geometry("400x500+500+120")
JanMenu.resizable(width=False , height=False)
JanMenu.overrideredirect(True)

def abrir():
    Saque.JanSaque.mainloop();

BtSaque = Button(FrmMenu, image = saque, bd = 0, cursor = 'hand2', bg = 'white', 
                                     command = abrir); #Botão saque
BtSaque.grid (row = 3, column = 0, pady = (20, 0), padx = (0, 250));

JanMenu.mainloop()
```

Tenho essa janela principal e quero que quando eu clicar no botão `BtSaque` abra a janela a `JanSaque` que é uma `instância` de `Tk` que está no arquivo `Saque.py`, mas quando eu executo o programa ele abre as duas telas na mesma hora. Alguém pode me ajudar? Só quero abrir outra janela após clicar no botão. Obrigado.

Comment: A pergunta não está clara o suficiente. Se há outro arquivo além deste, então não deveria haver outra sequência de código além dessa?

Comment: o que está no outro arquivo são apenas os widgets de sua tela, oq eu quero é que nessa tela eu consiga chamar esse outro arquivo (que é uma tela) após clicar no btSaque. Esse código de fazer abrir outra tela após no botão foi que eu não consegui fazer.

Answer (score 0):

O Tk abre uma janela logo quando se cria uma instancia dele e não no metodo mainloop().
Você precisa instanciar o Tk dentro do construtor da classe Saque e quando clicar na função abrir() criar uma instancia da classe Saque

Exemplo:

```
class Saque:
  def __init__(self):
    self.JanSaque = Tk()
    ...
```

E no botão criar uma instancia de Saque:

```
def abrir():
  s = Saque()
```